# Tensor calculus proof

Tags: integration, vectors, tensors

How can I show that

$$\int_{\Sigma}(φ ψ_{,i} - ψ φ_{,i})d^{2}x \ = \ \int_{\Omega}(φ ψ_{,ii} - ψ φ_{,ii})d^{3}x $$, where $ψ,φ$ are scalar functions of the coordinates. Then $i, ii$ designate differentiation of first and second order, and  $Σ, Ω$ are the surface and volyme respectively?

Comment: As far as I know, only Green-type theorem can save you here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Comment: I am not sure how the Green's theorem is related to this one. Green turn  a anintegrl over surface to line integral

Comment: He wrote "Green-type". It seems to be an application of the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) a.k.a. Gauss theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Divergence theorem on $\mathbb{R^3}$ (Gauss Theorem) for the vector field $\mathbf{F}=\varphi\nabla\psi$ is

$$
\int_\Sigma\varphi\nabla\psi\cdot \mathrm{d}\Sigma=\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot(\varphi\nabla\psi)\mathrm{d}\Omega\tag{1}
$$
With $\nabla\cdot(\varphi\nabla\psi)=\nabla\varphi\cdot \nabla\psi+\varphi\nabla^2\psi$ and using $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \nu}=\nabla \psi\cdot\hat{\nu}$ for the surface normal we can rewrite this as

$$
\int_\Sigma\varphi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \nu}\mathrm{d}\Sigma=\int_\Omega\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla\psi\,\mathrm{d}\Omega+\int_\Omega\varphi\nabla^2\psi\,\mathrm{d}\Omega\tag{2}
$$
This is a version of [Greens first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities)

Now we swap the scalar functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ in $(2)$ and subtract from $(2)$ and end up with
$$
\int_\Sigma\left(\varphi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \nu}-\psi\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \nu}\right)\mathrm{d}\Sigma=\int_\Omega\left(\varphi\nabla^2\psi-\psi\nabla^2\varphi\right)\mathrm{d}\Omega
\tag{3}$$

This is a version of [Greens second identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities).